# Spacy Module name is keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, keyword, spacy

I need to import the spacy language class from `spacy.lang.is`. However, `is` is a keyword within python and I am therefore getting conflicts in PyCharm IDE. Is there a way to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spacy docs](https://spacy.io/usage/models) recommend importing as follows:

```
from spacy.lang.is import Icelandic
nlp = Icelandic()
```

This should avoid reassigning the reserved keyword `is`.

If that still makes PyCharm complain, you could use `__import__`:

```
Icelandic = __import__('spacy.lang.is', globals(), locals(), ['Icelandic'], 0).Icelandic
```